# LibUV NodeJS handle synchronous or asynchronous tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callstack, event-loop, libuv

I'm Nodejs beginner. I have been reading some documents and posts on Google and as far as I know, LibUV is used to handle asynchronous tasks. However, when I came across a post recently, the author mentioned that LibUV is used to offload synchronous operations. (https://dev.to/johnjardincodes/increase-node-js-performance-with-libuv-thread-pool-5h10 )

> Libuv initiates a thread pool of 4 threads that it uses to offload synchronous operations to. In doing this, Libuv ensures that our application does not get blocked unnecessarily by synchronous tasks.

This has left me confused. Does this mean that synchronous tasks will be executed simultaneously in LibUV and the results will be returned to the main stack? Can someone please help me understand this better? Thank you !

Comment: Hi @Simba,
As per my understanding the article you mention it will help to improve the handle the more events.
```Node.js uses a small number of threads to handle many clients. In Node.js there are two types of threads: one Event Loop (aka the main loop, main thread, event thread, etc.), and a pool of k Workers in a Worker Pool (aka the threadpool).

If a thread is taking a long time to execute a callback (Event Loop) or a task (Worker), we call it "blocked". While a thread is blocked working on behalf of one client, it cannot handle requests from any other clients. ```
As per Node Doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this talk: [What the heck is the event loop anyway?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ). And check [this page from Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#what-is-the-event-loop). To see how Node.js uses libuv.

As per [libuv's documentation](https://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html#threadpool) it uses a thread pool of size 4 by default:

> *libuv provides a threadpool which can be used to run user code and get
> notified in the loop thread. This thread pool is internally used to
> run all file system operations, as well as getaddrinfo and getnameinfo
> requests.*
>
> *Its default size is 4, but it can be changed at startup time by
> setting the UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE environment variable to any value (the
> absolute maximum is 1024).*

Which means that when you perform an HTTP call with `request.get('URL', cb);` for example. The protocol itself is synchronous as you will send a request and wait for the response. But the Node.js APIs (libraries) expose asynchronous functions. It will push your Network I/O operations to libuv which reports back to your main Node.js thread once your response is resolved (or timed out).
While your network operations are being resolved outside JavaScript (thanks to `libuv`), you continue executing the rest of your JavaScript code. And your callback (`cb` in my example) will be pushed to a queue and only pulled to the call stack when you get something back from `C` libraries running under the hood.

JavaScript is synchronous by default and is single-threaded. That's why Node.js's V8 implements libuv library to handle most of the I/O operations which are expensive and sometimes blocking.

Read more:

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-multithreading-in-node-js#understanding-hidden-threads-in-node-js
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/libuv-in-node-js/
- https://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html

Comment: As you said, the HTTP call or request.get('URL', cb) appears to be synchronous, but in reality, Node.js marks it as asynchronous and passes it to libUV.

Comment: [libuv is a part of Node.js](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/libuv-in-node-js/) the fact that JavaScript thread delegates the I/O operations to libuv threads and only get back the results anytime later is what achieves the "asynchronous" behaviour. Synch/Asynch perspectives depends on which part (depth) of the stack you are using/studying